# The import org.bytedeco.leptonica.global.lept cannot be resolved

Tags: java, bytedeco-javacv

I am using `lept` import as following.

```
import static org.bytedeco.leptonica.global.lept.pixDestroy;
import static org.bytedeco.leptonica.global.lept.pixRead;
```

And after upgrading bydeco tesseract package to `5.2.0-1.5.8` from `5.0.1-1.5.7` I got error as following.

`The import org.bytedeco.leptonica.global.lept cannot be resolved`

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version `5.2.0-1.5.8` pixDestroy and pixRead is available under new `global.leptonica` which previously was `global.lept`

```
import static org.bytedeco.leptonica.global.leptonica.pixDestroy;
import static org.bytedeco.leptonica.global.leptonica.pixRead;
```